# How to add automated tests in azure build pipeline

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-devops, devops

I want to add some automation tests (it can be selenium c#/ java tests) to my existing azure pipeline. My pipeline is working correctly i.e. when I push changes to my master branch (GitHub), it triggers the build and it gets deployed to the live. But I want to integrate some automation test which will decide whether to deploy the build or not example:

After committing to the master branch:
run the automation test
if tests passed > deploy
if the test fails > stop deployment

Any suggestions or reference material would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Are the following replies helpful? Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of tests you are going to run - if they are unit tests, it is easy but selenium tests you would need to deploy it to a webserver before running the tests.

When edit the pipeline, and click "Show assistance" if is't not already done, you can see the tasks, including test dashboard etc.

For example if you add a VStests, it will add something like this to the yaml file.

`- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-- no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'`

Above just executes 'dotnet test' command which will look for tests in the project and run them.

It is executing a command line, so you can run any tests as far as you can provide a command line using batch/powershell commands.

The Microsoft tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-quality-tests-build-pipeline/ explains how to use the test wigits etc.

I would suggest to start with unit tests which is simpler before trying selenium.

Krish

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) under which each stage, job, or step runs. By default, a job or stage runs if it does not depend on any other job or stage, or if all of the jobs or stages that it depends on have completed and succeeded. By default, a step runs if nothing in its job has failed yet and the step immediately preceding it has finished.

In another word, if test step/job/stage passed, the next step/job/stage can precede.